# Can't find WebAPI method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js

I have declared a function on my API controller:

```
[HttpGet, Authorize]
public List<UIPhotoModel> GetPhotosByAlbumID(int AlbumID)
{
    ....
}
```

I call it from my javascript:

```
var urinocat = '/api/Photo/GetPhotosByAlbumID';
    $.get({ url: urinocat, contentType: "application/json" }, 0)
        .done(function (data) {
            vm.UncategorisedImages(data);
        });
```

And get:

```
GET http://localhost:54065/api/Photo/GetPhotosByAlbumID 404 (Not Found)
```

The only way I know how to fix it is to create a class, with an int in it, and pass accept that in my controller method. Why can't the API method be found?

All other ones work with I use a complex object and pass that bk to the controller. But an int - it fails.

Comment: try sending it as a string `"0"` . The documentation says that the data should be `A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.`
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/. Also, since you have `(int AlbumID)` at the server, it will be parsed into an `int`..

Comment: are you speaking about .net web api?  If you are using the default routing then I think you want GetPhotosByAlbumID(int id)  and your url will be  '/api/Photo/' + yourid ;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the request with a query string in the url like this:
http://localhost:54065/api/Photo/GetPhotosByAlbumID**/?AlbumID=1**